# Python Pandas inserir registros em uma coluna de acordo com os dados presentes em um DataFrame

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

#### Boa noite, tenho um planilha de Excel que possui uma coluna chamada `Cod` e dentro dessa coluna possui os `valores: 01, 02, 03`

Eu preciso criar uma outra coluna nessa tabela que faça o seguinte:

- De acordo com os valores da coluna "Cod" atribua os nomes das Cidades

Ex:

> 01 = São Paulo
>
> 02 = Belo Horizonte
>
> 03 = Rio de Janeiro

Ou seja essa outra coluna recebera os nomes das `Cidades` de acordo com o `Cod` delas, tentei fazer assim:

```py
data_teste = {'Cidades': ['São Paulo', 'Belo Horizonte', 'Rio de Janeiro']}
resultado = pd.DataFrame(data_teste, index=[01, 02, 03])
plan = pd.read_excel('teste.xlsx', header=3)

for i in plan['Cod'].values:
    if i in resultado.loc[i]:
        plan['Nomes Cidades] = resultado.values
```

Mas não obtive sucesso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Da para mostrar uma parte do `dataframe` plan?

Comment: @Sidon bom dia, o amigo `GBrandt` conseguiu solucionar este meu problema, em relação ao seu comentário daria pra mostrar sim, a parte que me interessava era a `Cod` e dentro dessa coluna me mostraria vários códigos ex: `01, 02, 03...` para cada `Cod` dentro dessa coluna precisaria de uma outra coluna chamada `Cidades` que iria atribuir o nome da cidade correta de acordo com aquele Cod, por exemplo o `Cod 01 = São Paulo | 02 = Belo Horizonte | 03 = Rio de Janeiro` basicamente era isso, espero que tenha entendido essa minha explicação rsrs, obrigado pelo interesse em querer ajudar, vlw mesmo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente com [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
plan['Nomes Cidades'] = plan['Cod'].map(resultado['Cidades'])
```

Comment: Obrigado @GBrandt funcionou perfeitamente da forma que eu queria, eu conhecia já o `map` mas não sabia que ele iria funcionar nessa ocasião, porque geralmente eu uso ele pra percorrer em uma lista, nessa caso ele percorreu em um DataFrame usando a `Key: Cidades` do meu dicionário, show de bola saber que dessa forma funciona também!